# GWT: Move Widget Animation

Tags: gwt

I want to make animation moving a button from nX, nY to n1X, n1Y during 1000 ms.

My class:
public class Start extends Animation implements EntryPoint {

```
AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();
Label label;
Button b;
int a;

@Override
protected void onUpdate(double progress) {

    panel.setWidgetPosition(b, 2*2, 2*2);
    a++;
}

public void onModuleLoad() {
    panel = new AbsolutePanel();
    b = new Button("Click!");
    label.setText("111");

    RootPanel.get().add(label);
    RootPanel.get().add(panel);

        }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Making animation in GWT is quite easy:

```
Timer r1 = new Timer() {
                int num = 100;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    widget.setStyleName("after");
 }
            };

Timer r = new Timer() {
                int num = 100;

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    widget.setStyleName("before");
                    num += 10;
                }
            };

r.scheduleRepeating(1000);
r1.scheduleRepeating(2000);`
```